# I have a dropdown in Javascript, but it is working fine in chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

div  class="list-show" data-action="option-tray">--> when clicked on dropdown box it should add display as block but it is always adding hidden in firefox. But it is working fine in chrome. I think there is some problem with " $(window).click(function(e) {
           base.$optionTray.hide();
        });"  code. I am not able to resolve it.

//This is the Typescript file which is compiled to javascript

```
private rootSelectionString: string = ".js-multiselectDropdown";
private actionButtonSelectionString: string = "*[data-action='colex']";
private optionTraySelectionString: string = "*[data-action='option-tray']";
private checkboxTraySelectionString: string = "*[data-action='checkbox-tray']";
private selectedClass= "selected";
private $rootElement: JQuery;
private $optionTray: JQuery;
private $checkboxTray: JQuery;
private $actionButton: JQuery;
private dataId;
private listLength;
private searchCheckedBoxes;
private checkBoxes;

constructor(el) {
    var base = this;
    base.$rootElement = $(el);
    base.$optionTray = base.$rootElement.find(base.optionTraySelectionString).eq(0);
    base.$checkboxTray = base.$rootElement.find(base.checkboxTraySelectionString).eq(0);
    base.$actionButton = base.$rootElement.find(base.actionButtonSelectionString).eq(0);
    base.optionPopulation();
    base.attachEvent();
    base.initialValueCapture();
}

private attachEvent() {
    var base = this;
    if(base.$rootElement.length!==0) {
        base.$optionTray.hide();  
        base.$actionButton.click(function(){
            event.stopPropagation();
            base.$optionTray.toggle();
        });

        $(window).click(function(e) {
           base.$optionTray.hide();
        });

        $(".list-show").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        base.$optionTray.find('li[data-id]').click(function() {
            base.$actionButton.find('span').html(""); 
            $(this).toggleClass(base.selectedClass);
            if($(this).hasClass(base.selectedClass)){
                base.$checkboxTray.find('[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').attr('checked','1');                  
            }
            else {
                base.$checkboxTray.find('[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').removeAttr('checked');
            }    

            base.searchCheckedBoxes = base.$rootElement.find('input:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
            });
            var dataArr=[];
            $.each(base.searchCheckedBoxes.get(),function(i,v) {
                dataArr.push(v);
            });
            if(dataArr.length!==0) {
                base.$actionButton.find('span').append(dataArr+","); 
            }
            else {
                base.$actionButton.find('span').html("Choose Tag"); 
            }         
       });
    }
}
```

//Here is the HTML code where the dropdown menu is displayed

```
<div class="js-multiselectDropdown" style="float:left">
    <div class="action-btn " data-action="colex"><span>Choose Tag</span></div>
    <div  class="list-show" data-action="option-tray">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-action="checkbox-tray" class="hidden">
         <input type="checkbox" value="O"/>O</br>
         <input type="checkbox" value="G" checked/>G</br>
         <input type="checkbox" value="E"/>E</br>
         <input type="checkbox" value="N" checked/>N</br>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: ReferenceError: event is not defined
This error comes when i click on dropdown box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, that the below function is not passing through the event property

```
base.$actionButton.click(function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    base.$optionTray.toggle();
});
```

Doesn't appear to take event in on the function(), I don't have a TypeScript compiler setup, but if you just add event into the function() definition, you should be good to go.

Comment: base.$actionButton.click(function(event){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    base.$optionTray.toggle();
                });
like this?

Comment: Your welcome, don't forget to tag the answer as accepted.